# Have authenticated and unauthenticated version of angular app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to build a secured angular app and not expose resources for authenticated users (js/templates) to unauthenticated users. (e.g. unauthenticated users can access to all .js when my app loads initially)

Is it a good idea to build two angular apps for a website? One that shows resources only to unauthenticated users, and once user logs in, redirects the user to the authenticated app.

Comment: you can check permission, and then load the secure files

Comment: @Shimbr Could you provide an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the secure files when the user logs in, with something like:

```
function addSrcs(fileName) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = fileName;

    script.onload = function() {
        console.log(fileName + ' loaded');
    };

    script.onerror = function() {
        console.log(fileName + ' Didn\'t load');
    };

    document.body.appendChild(script);
};
```